# Bootstrap navbar. Объект не растягивается на всю ширину экрана, container-fluid тоже не помог. HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Создала навбар с помощью бутстрапа, но его фон не на всю ширину экрана. При увеличении масштаба страницы справа фон не до конца. Навбар в контейнере, но всё равно не на всю ширину. Так же и другие блочные элементы не на всю.
Код страницы.

```css
.dropdown-item,
.nav,
.btn,
.dropdown-menu {
  color: white;
  background-color: #262222;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}

.dropdown-divider {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Biologist - все про біологію</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="settings.css">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: yellowgreen;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Biologist - твій універсальний довідник</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">ГОЛОВНА</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">6 КЛАС</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Вступ</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Клітина</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Одноклітинні організми. Перехід до багатоклітинності</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Рослини та їх різноманітність</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Гриби</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  7 КЛАС
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Вступ</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Різноманітність тварин</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Процеси життєдіяльності тварин</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Поведінка тварин</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Середовища існування тварин</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  8 КЛАС
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Вступ</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Обмін речовин та енергії</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Травлення</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Дихання</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Транспорт речовин в організмі</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Процеси виділення</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Опор та рух</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Нервова система та зв’язок з середовищем</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Сенсорні системи</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Вища нервова діяльність</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Регуляція функцій організму</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Розмноження і розвиток</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown4" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  9 КЛАС
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Хімічний склад клітин та молекул</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Структура клітини</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Принципи функціонування клітини</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Збереження і реалізація спадкової інформації</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Успадкування</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Еволюція органічного світу</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Біорізноманіття</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Надорганізмові біологічні системи</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Біологія як основа біотехнології та медицини</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown5" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  10 КЛАС
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Вступ</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Біорізноманіття</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Обмін речовин і енергії</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Спадковість і мінливість</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Репродукція та розвиток організмів</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown6" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  11 КЛАС
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Адаптації</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Біологічні основи здорового способу життя</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Екологія</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Сталий розвиток і раціональне природокористування</a></li>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Застосування результатів біологічних досліджень у селекції, біотехнології та медицині</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Введіть пошуковий запит" aria-label="Search" style="width: 230px;">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Пошук</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Что делать? Может я где-то ошиблась?

Comment: А уточните, что именно Вы хотите растянуть? Если `nav class="navbar"`, то он и так во всю ширину экрана (Вы ему ещё фон задали `yellowgreen`)

Comment: @Danila при увеличении масштаба страницы фон не до конца становится, элементы до конца, но вот фон нет(

Comment: Если указать в стиле width: fit-content; то проблема с увеличением масштаба решается, но вот проблема с уменьшением появляется - теперь весь навбар не до конца. Ну а если сделать ширину 100%, то опять же первоначальная проблема

Comment: @viktoriyaivanets, если я правильно вас понял, то у вас проблема с адаптацией. Решить её можно либо уменьшив блоки в nav-bar либо сделав "burger menu" ещё раньше

Comment: @HTO HOT да, проблема с адаптацией, но я не совсем понимаю, как её решить при изменении масштаба. Все нормально сворачивается, если не трогать масштаб.

Comment: @viktoriyaivanets на ширине 1360 скрывайте поиск и классы и показывайте бургер. Сейчас у вас показывается бургер на 991

Comment: @Александр Сычёв но мне хотелось бы, чтобы при увеличении масштаба страницы просто фон был на всех элементах, не сворачивался.